# macOS High Sierra on the App Store: the Learn More button doesn't work

Tags: mac-appstore

App Store > [macOS High Sierra](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/macos-high-sierra/id1246284741?mt=12) > Download

> We could not complete your purchase.
>
> You do not have enough space to install macOS High Sierra.
>
> [ Learn More ]  [ OK ]

That [ Learn More ] button does nothing at all. I opened the Console app and filtered the messages using "App Store" and I found this:

> Rejected request to open untrusted URL DABuyButtonLearnMoreURL.Yosemite

I'm running macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I thought I had enough space but I didn't. You need at least 14.3GB I believe. It downloaded for me afterwards

Comment: I didn't have enough space to install the upgrade, but I had some free space, so this should not have prevented the Learn More button from working.